# Gmail blue bar issue

Tags: gmail

[image]When I first open Gmail and my inbox loads there is a long blue line to the left of the top email. This disappears after I have opened an email and gone back to the Inbox. Has anyone heard of this issue or know a solution?

Comment: Can you post an image of this ?

Comment: Yes I have the image saved on my desktop.  I'm a brand new user so can you tell me how to post it?

Comment: Click on edit, Click on the "Image" Icon, and select Choose "Upload"

Comment: Thanks!  There it is!  Quite the mystery, eh?  You will be my hero if you figure this out!

Comment: which chrome version you are using ?

Comment: Version 32.0.1700.107 m

Comment: This looks more like a rendering issue than a Gmail issue. What happens if you open it in a different browser?

Comment: 1) Thanks for taking your time to help me  2) I don't know what "a rendering issue" means lol.  You'll have to explain  3) When I load gmail in IE it loads fine.  4) Since all I ever use is Chrome, I need to fix this in Chrome.  6) This weird thing just started out of the blue in Chrome about 3 weeks ago  7) Let's fix it!!  (Notice I said "let's" as though I have anything to do with it lol)

Comment: Try deleting Chrome’s cache and cookies and see what happens. If that doesn’t work, it could also have something to do with one (or more) of your extensions/add-ons.

Comment: Ah! I have lots of extensions

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have at least 10 extensions and at least one modifying the Gmail interface (i mean the battery % indicator in the top right corner) I suspect one of the extensions.

1. Turn all of them off.
2. If that solves your problem, then try turning them back on again one by one and you'll see which one causes your problem.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried the experiment of signing into my gmail from a different computer and it loaded properly so I'm guessing you are correct about the extensions. Is there an easy way to turn off all the extensions at one time or do I need to do them individually?

Comment: Well, to turn them off temporarily, you can open a new incognito window (`Ctrl+Shift+N`) and then you need to log in again. -- Otherwise I do suggest you to turn them off one by one: that way you can find out which one causes your problem and get rid of that. -- Needless to say: only enable those extensions you actually need.

Comment: Dude you totally rock! By trial and error I discovered it was a Tetris extension. The game of Tetris. I disabled it and then I uninstalled it. You figured out what's a lot smarter people then me and maybe even you could not figure out lol

Comment: @user3322006: If Daniel's answer brought you to the solution, the best way to show that is to "accept" it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer. (More in our [Help Center](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).)

Answer (score -1):

you have the setting icon on your right top click on it. Settings page will be loaded on the current screen (Not on the new tab) there this sentence `General label Inbox Account Filters Forwarding` you go and click on the `Inbox` there you will see `Inbox Type` select the `default` value and then go to the end of the page and click save changes. You will see the result as expected.

Comment: It was already set to default :-(